# Trouble with Param arguments for an Api

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to get all cities of a specific country from an API(https://countriesnow.space/). Im using Php and curl but the result says:

```json
{
  "error": true,
  "msg": "missing param (country)"
}
```

Im using a script which is given by but it does not work: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/1134062/T1LJjU52#4829d16f-0f4e-43ec-886e-68ebad1221d8

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/cities',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
"country": "nigeria"
}',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Could anyone tell me whats wrong here? Really cant tell whats the issue.

Comment: try with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'country=nigeria'

Comment: Does not work unfortunately, still the same error

Answer (score 2):

cURL will automatically set the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, when you pass a string value for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

But this is not supposed to be form data, but JSON. Add

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Content-Type: application/json']
```

to your cURL options, to let the API *know* you are in fact sending JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot perfect Tip!